# What is the difference between Ubuntu for android and Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

Since both are mobile os why name them differently ? Or am i missing something here ?

Comment: Take a look at [What is Ubuntu for Android?](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android) and [Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch).

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu Touch

Ubuntu Touch is a stand-alone OS for mobile devices. It is only in beta and being tested on the Nexus 3 device. Canonical has assured fans that they have [2 major manufacturers ready to ship Ubuntu Touch with their new mobile models](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/first-ubuntu-phone-available-october-says-shuttleworth). It will not merge with Android or any other device, and it is simply an Ubuntu OS for mobile devices.

[The full, official list of compatible devices can be seen here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices#Working_with_phablet-flash)

[image: image description should be here :P]

---

### Ubuntu for Android

Ubuntu for Android is like a comparability mediator between the Desktop Ubuntu OS and your phone. It acts like a link between your Android quad-core phone and your computer. Ubuntu for Android [will sit alongside Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android), giving you the original functionality of your handset. Furthermore, 'docking' it will give you an environment where both your computer and phone act as both a **phone** and **computer**. It's a bit of a mouthful, and a little hard to grasp, but you can watch this video to learn more: [Ubuntu for Android - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iv1Z7bf4jXY)

[image]

Comment: I have a samsung galaxy note 3 with Android. Can I install Ubuntu for Android on it?